# Group Jenkins "built jobs list" by parameter used to build each one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job that takes the github repository name as a parameter to the build (we'll call this parameter "project" from here on). This is neat because the unit tests for all my companies projects are run the same way, so I can specify the project that I want to test as a parameter. This saves me having to create many very similar jobs and replace them all with one "parameterized" job that runs the unit tests which accepts the "project" as a parameter.

The problem is that the "list of builds" of this job now has a mix of all the different projects. Finding a build which only fails in one project means that I have to go through each of the build jobs until I find the one which has the parameter of the "project" that I'm interested in. In short, debugging is a bit of a pain.

Is there a way to group the list of builds by a certain parameter? This would allow me to quickly see all the builds in each project (the builds would be grouped by the "project" parameter), which would be great.